# What's the correct interpretation for the relativity of simultaneity?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

I'm currently reading "Introduction to special relativity" by Resnick, and I have a question about the relativity of simultaneity.

He uses this example:

[image: S POV]

So, from the point of view of $S$, $S'$ is moving at speed $v$: $S$ perceives the two events in $A$ and $B$ as simultaneous and $S'$ doesn't.

Then there is another example that should be the specular situation:

[image: S' POV]

In this case $S'$ sees $S$ moving at speed $-v$, therefore the events are simultaneous for $S'$ but not for $S$.

Here is my question: these two situations are exactly the same situation seen from two different frames of reference, right? $S$ always perceives itself as stationary, therefore it sees $S'$ moving, and viceversa for $S'$.
Therefore I'm wondering: from their own points of view, do they both perceive the events as simultaneous? Who's the one that actually doesn't see the events happening at the same time?

My idea is that $S$ sees the events happening simultaneously, but, from its point of view, $S'$ won't see them being simultaneous. On the other hand, $S'$ actually sees the events happening at the same time, but for him $S$ doens't.
Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is right.

Comment: @trula I don't think it is. I've elaborated in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea is that S sees the events happening simultaneously, but, from its point of view, S' won't see them being simultaneous. On the other hand, S' actually sees the events happening at the same time, but for him S doens't. Is this interpretation correct?

No, this is not correct. In the first figure, $S$ sees the strikes happen at the same time, while $S'$ does not. In the second figure, the opposite is the case. If your interpretation were correct, then special relativity would really be of no use at all, since the "point" of using Lorentz transformations to change frames of reference is to *faithfully* represent what an observer in a different reference frame would see.

I think the problem here is that the drawing is a little misleading. It looks like the first frames in both of your figures are identical, except for a change of velocity $v \rightarrow -v$. This gives the impression that the lightning strikes in some sense "actually" happen at the same time, but that one of the observers is subsequently misled by their motion.

But this is not true. To see this let us stick to the frame of $S$. In this frame, the lightning strikes in Fig. 2 *do not happen at the same time*. The strike at $A$ happens first, then a little later the strike at $B$. Thus, in frame $S$, the situation illustrated in the top panel of Fig. 2 *never happens*. That is, the lightning strikes are never present at the same time, unlike what the figure seems to indicate. The observer in $S$ would really see first the lightning at $A$, then a little later the lightning at $B$.

Edit: I think the above can be clarified more by attaching some space-time coordinates to the events.

In Fig. 1, the strikes occur at the following space-time positions

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \text{Strike 1} & \text{Strike 2} \\
\mathrm{S:} \qquad &(t,x) = (0,A), \qquad & (t,x) = (0,B), \\
\mathrm{S':} \qquad &(t',x') = \left(-\gamma \frac{v}{c^2} A, \gamma A\right), \qquad
 & (t',x') = \left(-\gamma \frac{v}{c^2} B,\gamma B\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$. Note that since $A<0$ and $B>0$ according to the drawing (assuming that $x$ increases to the right), we see that in frame $S'$ strike $B$ occurs at a negative time, while $A$ occurs at a positive time. Thus, according to the observer in $S'$, strike $B$ occurs before strike $A$.

In Fig. 2, the strikes occur at the following space-time positions

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \text{Strike 1} & \text{Strike 2} \\
\mathrm{S:} \qquad &(t,x) = \left(\gamma \frac{v}{c^2} A, \gamma A\right), \qquad
 & (t,x) = \left(\gamma \frac{v}{c^2} B,\gamma B\right) \\
\mathrm{S':} \qquad &(t',x') = (0,A), \qquad & (t',x') = (0,B).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

These expressions look very similar to the case in Fig. 1 except for two differences: Firstly, we have made the replacement $v \rightarrow -v$, but second: *The strikes happen at different times and positions*. This is a *different physical situation* from the situation depicted in Fig. 1 - it is *not* the same situation, just seen from a different point of view.

Comment: I was actually misled by the impression that the two events actually happen at the same time and they are just perceived differently, so thank you for highlighting the fact that they do not, you explanation really clarified the concept.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! I understand the confusion, the figure is rather misleading.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same situations: they are two quite separate scenarios. In the first, the flashes are simultaneous in S but not in S', while in the second the flashes are simultaneous in S' but not in S.

The key point here is that a flat slice through time in S is a sloping slice through time in S' and vice-versa. To make it clear, let's suppose that in the very first picture at the top of your question, the two grey oblongs align at 12:00 in S. That means that it is 12:00 at A and at B. However, in S' when it is 12:00 at A it might be 12:01 at A', for example, and 11:59 at B'.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Suppose we are in the first situation but in the reference frame S' instead of S: in this case we perceive ourselves as stationary and we see S moving at speed -v relative to us. The two events happen in A=A' and B=B' when t=t'=0. From my point of view now I am at rest, so the two flashlight have to reach me at the same time don't they?

Comment: You cannot just have $A= A'$, $B = B'$ and $t = t'$. In relativity, you have to treat space and time together using space-time variables. If event 1 happens at $(t_A,x_A)$ in frame $S$ and at $(t'_A, x'_A)$ in frame $S'$, and event 2 happens at $(t_A, x'_B)$ in $S$: then the space-time coordinates for event 2 in $S'$ will *not* be $(t'_A, x'_B)$. In particular, the time coordinate will be different - some $t'_B$ which is not equal to $t'_A$.

Comment: No, you are still not taking in what I have said. You are assuming that when t=0 everywhere in S, t'=0 everywhere in S', which is the Newtonian idea of time and is completely wrong. If you consider a snapshot in which t'=0 everywhere in S', then the corresponding value of t varies all along the direction of travel in S. Conversely if you pick a snapshot when t=0 everywhere in S, then the value of t' varies throughout S'.

Comment: That is because planes of constant time in the two frames are tilted relative to each other. Imagine a horizontal plane centred on New York and a horizontal plane centred on London. Because of the curvature of the Earth, the two planes are tilted relative to each other. If you pick two points that are an equal distance above the New York plane, they will be at two different heights relative to the London plane, and vice versa.

Comment: Okay yes I'm starting to understand. Sorry for the misunderstanding but I'm self-studying it and it's a bit difficult to be sure to get it right sometimes. Thank you both

Comment: @fede it took me years to get my head around it, so by comparison you are picking it up at lightning speed! If I get the chance, I will add an extra example to my answer to make the point clearer, hopefully!